# How can I create and outsource a module in Unreal Engine 4 (ue4)?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I have implemented some code in Unreal Engine 4 that I would like to outsource so that it can be used in other projects. My goal would be to get a file that can be imported / incorporated into other projects.

The module includes folders, classes, behavior trees, and blackboards. All of them programmed using blueprints.

It would be something similar to externalizing or importing a .jar library in the Java programming language. But in Unreal Engine 4 using Blueprints or C ++.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Google plugin docs for ue4. You might also find the gameplay module docs interesting, they're C++ only but can be part of the makeup of a plugin. Plugins themselves can contain pretty much anything a full blown project does, including blueprints.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a plugin in UE4 and put C++ code or blueprints into it, that's already a module which can be distributed between different UE4 project's by dragging and dropping the folder into 'Plugins' folder which should be located in the root directory of UnrealEngine project. The only issue you may experience is forward compatibility as UE4 new releases very often change the existing APIs.
Also note that:
You can not reuse those modules in non UE related C++ project.